# Soft Question: Limitations of matrix use in proof demonstration?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, diophantine-equations

> It is common routine in algebra to make variable changes in proof demonstration. For instance, to examine the relationship between 2 variables, we often set $$x+y=u$$
>   $$x-y=v$$
>   For 3 variables, $$x+y=u$$
>   $$x+z=v$$
>   $$y+z=w$$
>   These linear transformations are obviously the scalar multiplication:
>   $$(u,v)={{(x, y )}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1\\
> 1&-1
> \end{bmatrix}}$$
>   and
>   $$(u, v,w )=
> {{(x, y,z )}\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1&0\\
> 1&0&1\\
> 0&1&1
> \end{bmatrix}}$$
>   My question is, besides the obvious restriction that the determinant of these matrices must be non-zero, are there any other ones? For instance,can one use matrices that are non-square as well?

Comment: I think you mean the *determinant* of the matrices.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What's preventing you from doing anything (correct) that you want?

Comment: Here is my problem, I am trying to prove that any 3 integers can be written as followed:$$ x=u+v$$ $$y=v+w$$ $$z=w+t$$. I know it's possible because I have tried it with real numbers and it works but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If you're trying to prove that, then what you want to prove is that the determinant is $\pm 1$, because that's equivalent.

Comment: How did you come up with that? Please enlighten me. Since the matrix is not square, how do I proceed?

Comment: You can solve for the three integers by applying the inverse matrix. The inverse matrix therefore has to have integer coefficients. That happens if and only if the determinant is $\pm 1$, because $\det(AA^{-1})=\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=1$, and since both matrices have integer coefficients their determinants are integers, and the only integers that can satisfy this equation are $\pm 1$.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that the determinant is $\pm 1$. My question remains, what if the matrix is not square?

Comment: Solve the equations in the usual way by bringing it to to reduced row echelon form, and it works if and only if what you end up with on the right hand side has integer coefficients. In the cases you're looking at that wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @MattSamuel, since the determinant must be $\pm 1$, since $A^2=|A^TA|$ is a square matrix, I guess $det A=det|A^TA|$, What do you think?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. There may be an easier way than I suggested though.

Comment: Solving the equations is not the real issue. Showing that no generality is lost thru this linear transformation is my concern.

Comment: If at the end you have everything expressed with integer coefficients, then you've constructively found the way to express those integers in the way you want. You literally have a formula for them, you can plug in any integer. Completely general.

Comment: Regarding the determinant of a non-square matrix:$A^T$ is no different than $A$. Writing $(x,y,z)$ is no different than $
\begin{bmatrix} 
x&\\
y&\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That's only true if you switch the side you multiply the vector on, unless your matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your input. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem @Num.